# Stop specific animation from Animator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject, animator

I am animating different gameobjects while using the same animator:

```
public void Balances()
 {
     if (Monitors[0].activeSelf)
     {
         MonitorAnimations[0].Play("Monitor1-Animation", -1, 0f);
         KeyAnimation.Play("Monitor1-KeyAnimation", -1, 0f);
     } else if (Monitors[1].activeSelf)
     {
         MonitorAnimations[1].Play("Monitor2-Animation", -1, 0f);
         KeyAnimation.Play("Monitor2-Key-Animation", -1, 0f);
     } else if (Monitors[2].activeSelf)
     {
         MonitorAnimations[2].Play("Monitor3-Animation", -1, 0f);
         KeyAnimation.Play("Monitor3-Key-Animation", -1, 0f);
     }
 }
```

The usecase is: the user can switch between different monitors and each monitor has an own KeyAnimation. What I would like to achive is to stop for example "Monitor1-KeyAnimation" when Monitors[0] get's disabled.

I only found:

```
myAnimation.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;
```

which disables the animator completely, so it also stops the other animations from playing.

Has anyone an idea how I can achieve the right behaviour?

Comment: I would use a transition from `Any` to your idle/default state and as a condition have a `Trigger` like e.g. `Stop` and then simply on all other animators set `SetTrigger("Stop")` so they all go back to their idle state

Comment: And for the `KeyAnimation` .. isn't anyway each call to `Play` changing the state => any previous animation stops automatically .. so again I would use a default state and a trigger and in your monitors set that trigger in `OnDisable`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I didn't thought about using triggers. Currently when you switch the monitor, the old KeyAnimation is played until the end which leads to weird glitches.